# KnockoutMapping: ComputedObservables in parent model are not updated after loading data

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to load data via an ajax call from the server and map it via knockout mapping plugin into my knockout data model. The loading of the data works, only problem is that in the parent model the computed observables are not updated anymore. Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Created a fiddle to demonstrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/N9Pmt/27/

Comment: Please tell me someone else has seen the typo in the title of this question. (Apologies if this isn't constructive, but I did do a little laugh!). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data contains `sumtest: 0`.  This ends up replacing the existing `computed` with a new observable by the end of the mapping process.  The existing computed still gets re-evaluated, but the binding can no longer find it, since it has been replaced.

One solution is to ignore `sumtest` in your mapping options like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/N9Pmt/28/

Comment: Great, it works! But what if i have a lot of computed values in my model, do i have to add them all to the ignore list? What would be another solution?

Comment: Another solution would be to update the array directly, so call the mapping against just the array of items like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/N9Pmt/29/